# Setting DefaultButton to button.UniqueID throws exception

Tags: asp.net, defaultbutton

The problem I'm trying to solve:

I have several text boxes in an `asp:Panel`. When the user hits `Enter` from any of those boxes, I want the form to submit as if they've clicked `btnAddTag`. (When the cursor is not in those boxes, I have a different default submit button.)

The aspx:

```
<asp:Panel id="thePanel" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddTag" Text="Add Tag" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The vb:

```
tagPanel.DefaultButton = btnAddTag.UniqueID
```

The exception:

> The DefaultButton of 'tagPanel' must
>   be the ID of a control of type
>   IButtonControl.

The value of `btnAddTag.UniqueID` is `ctl00$phMain$btnAddTag` (there's a master page, this section is called `phMain`).

I've also tried `CType(tagPanel.FindControl("btnAddTag"), Button).UniqueID`.

Comment: in my situation, I was missing an outer `<asp:panel>` in which I didn't know i needed. Just thought i'd share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do:

```
tagPanel.DefaultButton = btnAddTag.ID
```

more info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx

Comment: That worked! Although I have no idea why, everywhere else I seem to need UniqueID...

Comment: You must use a relative "path". Meaning, use a string similar to the UniqueID so that it provides a path from the container down to the child control.

I've never seen this documented anywhere other than in Q/A posts. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/103530/defaultbutton-in-panel-for-wizard-errs

Answer (score 0):

You should set the control's ID not UniqueID:

tagPanel.DefaultButton = btnAddTag.ID